# Rails 5 - resque undefined method `namespace' for main:Object

Tags: redis, ruby-on-rails-5, resque, resque-scheduler

I was unable to run my rails server in development mode. I have installed two gems are **resque** and **resque-scheduler** into rails application. I have searched for the solution online but still, I was struggling with it.

Gemfile:

```
 gem 'resque'
 gem 'resque-scheduler'
```

Config file of application:

```
 config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
```

The resque.rake file:

```
 require 'resque/tasks'
 require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'

 namespace :resque do
    puts "Loading Rails environment for Resque"
  task :setup do
    require 'resque'
    require 'resque-scheduler'

    Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379'
  end
 end
```

Comment: `resque.take` -> `resque.rake`?

Comment: Sorry, yes that is a rake file. I made a small mistake. I have changed it.

Comment: have you created this task it `lib/tasks`? otherwise you need to add `rake` as well (but it is a worse kind of practice)